# Can I run separate asp.net c# page load events using JQuery multipage/same file data-role=page?

Tags: c#, jquery

So,

I'm using a c# code-behind in my mobile web site.

I need to run different `Page_Loads` based on which page is being displayed using Jquery Mobile `data-role="page"` attribute.

Ex: I have

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
  <div data-role="content">Content</div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
  <div data-role="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

Depending on which "page"(div) was loaded, how can I run a `Page_Load` on code behind?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. `Page_Load` runs on the server long before any javascript is interpreted.